# Mockito ArgumentCaptor verify that nothing is captured

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I need to verify that the ArgumentCaptor has not captured anything. Is there any way to verify this?

```
Mockito.verify( /* captor has not captured anything */ )
```

Comment: You can verify that the method was not called with a certain argument... `Mockito.verify(mock,never()).methodToBeCalled(argumentNotExpectedToBePassed)`

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Yes, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can verify that the number of captured values is equal to zero.

```
Assert.assertEquals(0, captor.getAllValues().size());
```